# Magento-2 Style attribute value on frontend

Tags: attributes, magento-2.1, frontend-model

I have created attribute using install script

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'mydemo',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => 'Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Frontend\Style',
                'label' => 'My Demo',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => 0,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
```

My frontend model file :

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Frontend;

class Style extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\AbstractFrontend
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\BooleanFactory $attrBooleanFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($attrBooleanFactory);
    }


    public function getValue(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $object)
    {
        $data = '';
        $value = parent::getValue($object);

        return "<b>{$value}</b>";
    }
}
```

I want to show attribute value bold on frontend but it's not working. Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got solution as below:

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Frontend;

class Style extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\AbstractFrontend
{

    public function getValue(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $object)
    {
        $this->getAttribute()->setData(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::IS_HTML_ALLOWED_ON_FRONT, 1);
        $data = '';
        $value = parent::getValue($object);

        return "<b>". $value ."</b>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe would be better to move that to an update script: $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'mydemo',
    [
        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 1,
    ]
);